# OpenGL GLX not using direct rendering. AMD proprietary drivers

Tags: 14.04, graphics, ati, steam, opengl

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, these are my specs:

8gb ram

Intel® Core™ i3-2120 CPU @ 3.30GHz × 3

Radeon r7 240

I installed the latest proprietary drivers from AMD using their guide to install the packages. But I can't get the direct rendering to work, and I'm getting errors when loading Steam. PlayOnLinux is unable to find 32bits OpenGL libraries. I've spent the last couple of days trying to figure out a fix through googling various phrases but to no avail...

This is my glxinfo:

```
    $ glxinfo
name of display: :0
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)
server glx vendor string: ATI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R7 200 Series  
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 (4.5.13416 Compatibility Profile Context 15.302))
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_fragment_program, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_imaging, 
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, 
    GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_shadow_ambient, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_vertex_program, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATIX_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_EXT_abgr, 
    GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, 
    GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, 
    GL_EXT_point_parameters, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color, 
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, 
    GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_EXT_texture_lod, 
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_vertex_array, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SGIX_shadow_ambient, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays

49 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x023 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x024 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x025 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x026 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x027 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x028 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x029 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x030 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x031 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x032 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x033 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x034 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x035 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x036 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x037 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x038 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x039 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x03a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x03b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x040 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x041 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x042 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x043 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x044 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x045 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x046 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x047 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x048 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x049 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x04a 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x04b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x04c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x04d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x04e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x04f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x050 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x051 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x052 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0aa 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Ncon

53 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x023 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x024 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x025 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x026 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x027 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x028 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x029 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x02c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x02d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x02e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x02f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x030 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x031 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x032 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x033 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x034 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x035 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x036 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x037 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x038 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x039 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x03a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x03b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x040 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x041 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x042 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x043 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x044 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x045 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x046 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x047 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x048 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x049 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x04a 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x04b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x04c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x04d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x04e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  6 1 None
0x04f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x050 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x051 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x052 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0aa 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Ncon
0x0aa 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Ncon
0x0aa 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Ncon
0x0aa 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Ncon
0x0aa 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Ncon
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm it seems something went wrong during the installation.. also it tells you to use **LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose** before running **glxinfo** in order to debug the issue! See if that helps you finding out!

did you install the catalyst from the amd site and not with a .deb? Generally i suggest you not install any drivers from outside the repositories.

I can suggest 3 alternatives if LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose doesnt help:

1. uninstall them (i dont really know how) and install the ones from the repository.(Go to Additional Drivers and install them from there) I'm not sure if they are the latest ones, but if not they will probably be updated soon. This is the most recommended solution, since you dont need to upgrade your distro version!
2. Need a more recent driver NOW? then i suggest you upgrade to 15.10 and install the catalyst from there (after uninstaling the current driver)
3. You dont need to install a catalyst driver, unless you want the latest opengl features and are a heavy gamer. In general the default open-source drivers on 15.10 can play most games and can have better performance in wine (if using gallium nine from  [ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-updated-and-optimized-open-graphics-drivers-radeon-intel-and-nvidia-on-ubuntu-15-0414-04.html))